# Angular directive not compiling correctly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

> app.directive('alert',function($timeout){
>
> ```
>     return {
>         restrict:'E',
>         scope : {
>             insidemsg:'=',
>             alertType:'=',
>             disappear:'='
>         },
>         replace:true,
>         template:'<div class="alert alert-{{alertType}}"><p class="text-danger">{{insidemsg}}</p></div>',
>         link: function(scope,element,attrs){
>             if(scope.disappear==true){
>                 $timeout(function(){
>                     element.remove();
>                 }, 5000);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```

This is the code for the directive.

`var el = angular.element($compile( '<alert insidemsg="ohoh" alert-type="danger" disappear="true"></alert>' )( $scope ));`

`$scope.el.append( el );`

The above is the code which is to compile the directive. But, the values are not getting mapped correctly.

i tried both `{{insidemsg}}` and `insidemsg` but nothing works.

I'm not sure what i was doing wrong.

Comment: `ohoh` should be a variable defined on scope.

Comment: What if i want that to be plain text value?

Comment: You can get the value in the link function using `attrs.insidemsg`. You can assign it to a scope.variable in directive and show it.

Comment: Ok i figures the answer. I should have used @ instead of = in directive scope declaration

Comment: Aaaaah, right i was not sure about that.